# Drools Kie Builder - Unable to build MavenEmbedder error

Tags: drools, kie

Getting following error while calling kieBuilder.buildAll() , though this not affect  the flow and the code gets successfully executed. How to get rid of this error ?

> Driver [ERROR] MavenEmbedder - Unable to build MavenEmbedder
>   org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException:
>   java.util.NoSuchElementException
>         role: org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulator   roleHint:     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:267)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:249)
>     at
>   org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.PlexusComponentProvider.lookup(PlexusComponentProvider.java:42)
>     at
>   org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.buildMavenExecutionRequest(MavenEmbedder.java:134)
>     at
>   org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.(MavenEmbedder.java:96)
>     at
>   org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.(MavenEmbedder.java:87)
>     at
>   org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.(MavenEmbedder.java:81)
>     at
>   org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.newMavenEmbedder(MavenProjectLoader.java:92)
>     at
>   org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:76)
>     at
>   org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:70)
>     at
>   org.appformer.maven.integration.MavenPomModelGenerator.parse(MavenPomModelGenerator.java:34)
>     at
>   org.appformer.maven.support.PomModel$Parser.parse(PomModel.java:110)
>     at
>   org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildPomModel(KieBuilderImpl.java:509)
>     at
>   org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.getPomModel(KieBuilderImpl.java:486)
>     at
>   org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.init(KieBuilderImpl.java:149)
>     at
>   org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:208)
>     at
>   org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:184)